# Terminal: change to admin user

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal

Right now I am logged in to Terminal as a standard user, is there a way to sudo as the admin user?

Comment: Which kind of terminal? Which OS?

Comment: Terminal on Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `sudo bash`, or sudo to whatever shell you want to use.

(I know this shouldn't be an answer, but I have to low rank to comment and the questioner seem to be in a hurry.)

Comment: Seems to work...I used su 'User Name' and entered the password, that seems to work too.

Comment: I haven't used OS X since Mac OS 1.3. I thought the use of `su` was blocked (other then with `sudo su`). Guess I remember wrong.

Comment: Also, using `su` is a bad habit, `sudo` and `sudoedit`prevents you from a lot of mistakes (I know, I've done most of them), especially when you have many terminal-windows open as different users and if you happen to do something in the wrong window.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you're not allowed to su to root but you can su to any other user.

Comment: you cannot use sudo as a standard user in os x. what he was asking is if you can become the admin user while logged in as a standard user, to which the answer is su. nothing is wrong with using su. whats wrong is su-ing to root and carelessly executing commands from a root shell.

Comment: - peelman , I see, I misinterpreted the question slightly. If you use `su`, wouldn't `su -` be more appropriate in most cases (sets environmental variables to the same values that they would have been set if the user logged in, i.e. runs some login scripts and bashrc).